# Share FSDataInputStream between Mappers?

Tags: java, database, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a job where I want to access the same file across multiple Mappers. Initially I tried opening and seeking into the file in each mapper, but this proved to be incredibly slow.

Is it possible to open the file in `run()` method (where I do things like `job.SetOutputPath` etc) and then share this open file with the Mappers so I don't have the incredible overhead of 100s of Mappers opening the same file separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is in fact possibble. If you set up the distributed cache and load files to it before the job begins it will automatically be sent to the mappers.

Example Distributed Cache setup:

```
String fileLocation;//set this to file absolute location
Configuration conf; //job Configuration

DistributedCache.addLocalFiles(conf,fileLocation);
conf.set("fileLocation",fileLocation);
```

Retrieve in Mapper setup method:

```
Configuration mapConf = context.getConfiguration();

URI[] cacheURIArray = DistributedCache.getCacheFiles();

String file2Location = mapConf.get("file2Location");

List<String> fileWords = new ArrayList<String>(); //set this as a clas variable so it can be accessed outside of the setup method of the mapper

for(URI uri: cacheURIArray){
    if( uri.toString().matches(".*"+fileLocation)){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStream(cacheFileSystem.open(new Path(uri.toString()))));
        String line = "";
        line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null){
            fileWords.add(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Your method of retrieval will likely be at least somewhat different form the example I provided, however it serves to illustrate how to use Distributed Cache. For more info look at [Distributed Cache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html)